# PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128 and AES Modes like GCM

Tags: aes, passwords, gcm

I've asked this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233296/pbewithhmacsha512andaes-128-and-aes-modes-like-gcm)

And I think one gentleman has already answered the first part of question

> **a)** In my code i am keeping IV and salt with ciphertext. I wanted to use `AES/GCM` to check integrity of entire IV + salt.

I've got the following answer and I'm fine with it:

> `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128` does not come with flexibility of
>   specifying mode like `GCM`

Can you please help me with the next question:

> **b)** Why the byte [] of key is 9 bytes? (When I give input as `Pree@2017` the key generated is 9 bytes - I have check the length of
>   `pbeKey.getEncoded()` and its 9.

Can anyone from the community help please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the byte [] of key is 9 bytes? (When I give input as Pree@2017 the
>   key generated is 9 bytes - I have check the length of
>   pbeKey.getEncoded() and its 9.

The length of "Pree@2017" is 9 chars.
The reason why you are getting the original password is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39979158/5088142)

> When you generate a SecretKey using the SecretKeyFactory
>   PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 you will get an instance of
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKey and this class has the "special
>   feature" that it returns the original "key" (aka password) when
>   calling getEncoded() and not the cryptographic key material. If I
>   understand it correctly the key derivation will not be made by the
>   KeyFactory but by the Cipher itself.
>
> Therefore you should not try to convert the SecretKey instance into a
>   SecretKeySpec instance; instead just use the generated SecretKey
>   instance in the correct cipher instance:
>
> ```
> Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
> c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
> ```